# its is true that he want help me?

Tags: scams

yesterday i got pm by online buyer for gold coin from oversea, and he want my id picture for security he said..but the deal is canceled because his manager not interested at that coin..today he said he want to help me and willing to give me money if i help him..he said he got staff around my state, and the staff will transfer him money every week, but it hard because got so many staff, it will make commotion..so he ask me to open an account bank in this state using my name so it will make easier the staff to transfer money if in same country..so all the staff will tranfer money to me, and latter ill transfer to him using online bank in..he ask me to give the back account and password so he can monitor the money inside..it willing to pay me every week if ill help..yesterday ask for my I.D and today ask to open bank account..it is a scam?please help me

Comment: This definitely, 100% sounds like a scam to me.

Comment: ***Scam / Fraud***

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it’s a scam. Best case you will end up with nothing, worst case you wil end up losing money and facing criminal charges for fraud and/or money laundering.

Do not contact him again or respond to further contact. Forward his details to your local law enforcement if you have provided any of your personal information to him already.

Comment: sir about the I.D that i have send?you think it will be safe?he cant use the ID without permission?

Comment: @SyafiqAsraf He absolutely can use the ID without permission, and he probably will.  That's almost certianly why he asked you for it - to use it as part of further identity theft schemes.

Comment: @Steve-O..so, what should i do sir?

Comment: @SyafiqAsraf, it depends on what country you are in.  In the US, you can hire identity protection services.  In any case, you need to close that bank account and, if possible, switch banks.